# Uncaught TypeError: this._triggerEvent is not a function at jQuery SmartCart

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart

Got this error when updating the quantity or remove an item from the cart. Any idea how to solve this?

```
    _triggerEvent: function (name, params) {
        // Trigger an event
        var e = $.Event(name);
        this.cart_element.trigger(e, params);
        if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            return false;
        }
        return e.result;
    }
```

---

```
    _removeFromCart: function (unique_key) {
        var mi = this;
        $.each(this.cart, function (i, n) {
            if (n.unique_key === unique_key) {
                var itemRemove = mi.cart[i];
                mi.cart.splice(i, 1);
                $('*[data-product-unique-key="' + unique_key + '"]').removeClass('sc-added-item');
                mi._hasCartChange();

                // Trigger "itemRemoved" event
                this._triggerEvent("itemRemoved", [itemRemove]);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/techlab/SmartCart)

[jQuery Script Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Interactive-Shopping-Cart-Plugin-For-jQuery-SmartCart/)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZygc.png)

[image]

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmCp5.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. I have changed this code
From `this._triggerEvent("itemRemoved", [itemRemove]);` To `mi._triggerEvent("itemRemoved", [itemRemove]);` at line 291

AND
`this._triggerEvent("quantityUpdated", [mi.cart[i], qty]);` To `mi._triggerEvent("quantityUpdated", [mi.cart[i], qty]);` at line 318